# Permissions on log files created by log4j RollingFileAppender

Tags: java, log4j, file-permissions, rollingfileappender

How are the permissions for files created by `RollingFileAppender` determined?

I recently changed a daemon process I have to be run as a non-root user and the files are now being created with permissions of `0600` (only readable by the owner), but I would like them to be readable by all or at least members of an admin group (`0644` or `0640`).  Files created by my tomcat apps are always `0644` (readable by all).

I don't know if I inadvertently changed something else or if it is something to do with permissions of that user.  I made the parent directory `0777` as a test and it didn't seem to help (it was `0755`).  Obviously not a big deal since I can `sudo` to look at them, but rather annoying and it will be a problem if I have to have a customer copy them for me.

Environment is Ubuntu 10.04LTS using `jsvc/commons-daemon` to run the daemon. In case it matters here is the basics on my `log4j` config:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM 'log4j.dtd'>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">

<appender name="StdOutAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- only send error / fatal messages to console (catalina.out) -->
    <param name="threshold" value="${log4j.StdOutAppender.threshold}" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        <!--%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %c{2}.%M [line:%L]: %m%n-->
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="TimeBasedRollingFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <param name="threshold" value="${log4j.TimeBasedRollingFileAppender.threshold}" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${cloud.daemon.log4j.file.config.path}.%d.gz" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        <!--%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %c{2}.%M [line:%L]: %m%n-->
    </layout>
</appender>
....
```

Comment: I realize this is a very old question, but there is a [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1699) scheduled to be fixed in 2.8.1 that would enable setting these permissions explicitly.

Comment: Numerical permissions are more clearly expressed as positional r w x characters, as suggested by your parenthetical notes. The "symbolic mode" of chmod supports these too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

File permissions are determined by the user's umask - there's not a way to change it in log4j itself.

You probably want to set the user's umask to `0117`

```
$ umask -S 0117
u=rw,g=rw,o=
```

Comment: Thanks -- I completely forgot about the umask.  Turns out, now that I know what to google for, that jsvc hard codes the umask so I may have to live with it (or recomplie jsvc) -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-178.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate.  Log4j 2.9.0 added a way to configure this without changing the umask setting.

Answer (score 15):

Log4J-core-2.9 will provide this [feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1699) *fileOwner*, *fileGroup* and *filePermissions* for posix OS in *FileAppender*, *RollingFileAppender* and *RollingRandomAccessFileManager*:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile"
             fileName="mylogs.log"
             filePattern="mylogs-$${date:MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.7z"
             fileOwner="log4j"
             fileGroup="log4grp"
             filePermissions="rw-r-----">
```

Comment: How this can be doen for logback?

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old question, but since it was the first hit still when I searched for this problem...

You can simply subclass `RollingFileAppender` and set the permission on the file when it is first opened, like this:

```
public class WorldWritableFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {
    @Override
    public synchronized void setFile(String fileName, boolean append,
            boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        super.setFile(fileName, append, bufferedIO, bufferSize);
        File f = new File(fileName);
        if(f.exists()) {
            java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(f.toPath(), 
                    EnumSet.allOf(PosixFilePermission.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Then just reference `WorldWritableFileAppender` instead of `RollingFileAppender` in your `log4j.xml`.

```
<appender name="name" class="path.to.WorldWritableFileAppender">
```

This works because `setFile()` is called both when originally setting up the logger, and when creating a new file after rollover. The old file is moved aside with `File.renameTo()`, which preserves the permissions.

Comment: This is really helpful when locked into LOG4j v1.

Answer (score 2):

inside log4j.properties include this: `log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/log`
anyway, this is my configuration that show info in console and file "log".

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/test
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your pom file:

```
<plugin>                
  <groupId>
     org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven- plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
   <jvmArguments>
     -DUMASK="0022"
     -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK="0022"
   </jvmArguments>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```