# log4cxx set file permissions for log files

Tags: c++, apache, log4j, log4cxx

I am trying to configure log4cxx using following properties file as per [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) log4j config.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, TEST
log4j.appender.TEST=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TEST.fileName=/var/log/test/test.log
log4j.appender.TEST.fileOwner="log4j"
log4j.appender.TEST.fileGroup="log4grp"
log4j.appender.TEST.filePermissions=rw-rw-rw-
```

**fileOwner, fileGroup, filePermissions** options doesn't seems to work as log files are generated with different permissions. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893511/permissions-on-log-files-created-by-log4j-rollingfileappender) **umask** works fine but is there a way I could set log permissions using log4cxx config file itself??

Comment: Ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately haven't yet received any. We fixed the issue by creating a patch around log4cxx.